# I can't deploy my firebase function, I got the error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully

Tags: javascript, firebase, powershell, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

For my project, I was trying to create and use a function to delete a specific user from Firebase Auth. But I learned that I can't do it from client-side.After that situation, I have started to learn and use Firebase Functions. They look pretty easy but when I try to deploy It says successfully but clearly is not.

As I explained above, here is my PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\herob\OneDrive\Masaüstü\web-projects\##myprojectname##> firebase deploy --only functions:deleteUserByUid

=== Deploying to '##myprojectname##'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and anaylzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8735

shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error
```

Here is my function:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const { auth } = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { logger } = require("firebase-functions");

initializeApp();

exports.deleteUserByUid = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const uid = data.uid;
  const db = getFirestore();
  const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
  const userDoc = await userRef.get();
  if (!userDoc.exists) {
    logger.error("User does not exist");
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "not-found",
      "User does not exist"
    );
  }
  try {
    await auth().deleteUser(uid);
    await userRef.delete();
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "internal",
      "Error deleting user"
    );
  }
  return { success: true };
});
```

My firebase.json file:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions/",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I am sure about

- I am already logged in to Firebase
- I have init the Firebase.
- I am using my own project with 'firebase use project_id_or_alias'

I tried:

- delete functions and re-initialize functions.

I was expecting to see my function after all these but I can't.

Comment: I don't see that your function deployed successfully.  It looks like there was an error.

Comment: If you mean 

`Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error`

I think it occurred because of lint. It can't check if the function has the correct syntax or not.